# Keyboard's light is not working

Tags: keyboard, macos

When I press the F5/F6 button, the HUD shows a decreasing/increasing bar related to the keyboard's brightness (image).

[image]

So far so good… The problem is: the keyboard stays completely dark, no light is emitted from the keyboard, even though the bar is moving when I press the keys F5 and F6.

I've already tried to reset PRAM and SMC but it didn't fix my problem. What should I do?

Comment: Image is in a private area. Post to somewhere like imgur, flikr & paste the link here; then someone with the necessary reputation can inline it for you

Comment: @Tetsujin done!

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Keyboard in System Preferences, there is a check box titled "Adjust keyboard brightness in low light".  If that is turned off, does your problem still present itself?

Comment: @PauloWaldo yes, it does. I`ve already tried both opitions but no nothing changed =/